# constructing Dynamic url using jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor, href

I'm trying to construct a anchor tag href where the url will be querying a service

the code:

```
var href  = $("#id").text();
$('<a href="#" id="testselect">button</a>').insertAfter("#searchtextselecttest");
$("#testselect").attr('href','http://something/ID='+ href);
```

when I click on the link, I just get the "something/ID=" and the href is not appended and #id is a link aswell!!

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with your HTML code?

Comment: try `var href = $("#id").prop("href")` if `"#id"` is a link and you want its `href`

Comment: debug, `href` returns anything ?

Comment: I agree with Conner, you should use jsfiddle to explain what you need. Chances are you'll find your own solution when building your fiddle.

Comment: And are you sure that #id is not empty? The code should work, and properbly does.

Comment: @ BjarkeCk The intial value is empty but the value is updated via appending  a value and then I'm calling this!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var href = encodeURI($("#id").text());
$('<a href="#" id="testselect">button</a>').insertAfter("#searchtextselecttest");
$("#testselect").attr('href','http://something/ID='+ href);
```

Comment: Then the other guys are probably right - your `$("#id").text()` doesn't have any contents. What type of element is that? Use FireBug or the like to step into your code and check the value, or do an `alert($("#id").text())`